# use javascript to print textfiled value to page

Tags: javascript, function, textfield, document.write

how can i get the value typed into the textfield with javascript and print it to the page? I am able to use an alert to see the value typed into the textfield but I am unable to get the value from the function for the textfield to print out to the page. 
My code is here: http://jsbin.com/olokoq/2

Answer (score 0):

In `SelectSubCat` you need to add the following:

```
document.getElementById('value').innerHTML = txtValue;
```

Then in your html add:

```
<span id="value"></span>
```

This will insert the value of the text input, into the span tag as soon as you click the button.

Comment: doesn't work, does <span id="value"></span> have to be inside script tags?

Comment: no, it has to be somewhere within your html's body (anywhere, it shouldn't matter)

Comment: it doesn't work it only prints You typed: and i used <br />
<p>You typed: <span id="valuessss"> </span></p> with document.getElementById('vvaluessss').innerHtml = txtValue; in selectsubcat

Answer (score 0):

```
inside your html text field call a function on onkeyUp or relevent function 

<input type='text' id='id1' onKeyUp='name(this.value);' value='name_value' />

function
<script>
function name(var_value){
document.getElementById("print").value = var_value; // print in a text field
document.getElementById('prnt').innerHtml = var_value; // print in a division 
}
</script>

<div id = 'prnt' ></div>

<input type='text' id='print'  value='name_value' />
```